# character class has duplicated range:/ regular expression of email/

Tags: ruby, regex, web-scraping, mechanize, anemone

result of xmpfilter

```
doc.search('.noimage p:nth-child(5)') do |kaipan|
    x = kaipan.to_s 
    x.scan(/[\w\d_-]+@[\w\d_-]+\.[\w\d._-]+/) #=>  # !> character class has duplicated range: /[\w\d_-]+@[\w\d_-]+\.[\w\d._-]+/
end
```

If I don't use {do~end},It's just how I expected it.Like the following.

```
[9] pry(main)> doc.search('.noimage p:nth-child(5)').to_s.scan(/[\w\d_-]+@[\w\d_-]+\.[\w\d._-]+/)
=> ["xxxxxx@live.jp"]
```

Posting here made me realize again that I suck at English...lol 
I'm Japanese.
This is my first post of Stackoverflow.

Comment: your regex works fine for me. What's the problem with that? It would be better if it is `[\w-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w-]+`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have a look at [this faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help) when you have time.

Answer (score 1):

The warning message (it is a warning and not an error, you will only see it if warnings are enabled) is `character class has duplicated range`. A character class in a regexp is the contents inside `[...]`, so in your case that is `[\w\d_-]`, and the warning is telling you that it has a “duplicated range”. What this means is  part of the character class is specifying the same characters that another part specifies.

If we break the class down into its parts, `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (see [the Regexp docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes)), and `\d` is the same as `[0-9]`. But `0-9` is already included in `\w`, so this range is duplicated which is what the warning is telling you. `_` is also included in `\w`,so you can leave `\d` and `_` out of your regexp and change it to `[\w-]`, which should have the same effect with no warnings.

Also note that `-` is a meta character inside a character class, so whilst it seems to work here you probably would be safer to escape it: `[\w\-]`.

Comment: The correct expression is `[\w-]` because you don't need to escape the `-` when it's the last char in the `[]`. Sintaro0221 actually got that part right, surprisingly (though it was probably accidental :p).